# Comparing with null in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm useing EF as ORM. I have table "Menu" in my database with column "parentID"(nvarchar) that can be NULL. I want get all menus, that have parentId == NULL. When i write this, it's work(menus have all nesseccary menu):

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{                    
    IEnumerable<Menu> menus = db.Menus.Where(m => m.ParentId == null).ToList();
}
```

But this code doesn't work (menus equals null):

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{    
    string parentId = null;
    IEnumerable<Menu> menus = db.Menus.Where(m => m.ParentId == parentId).ToList();                    
}
```

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: Are you sure it is null and not an empty list?  It seems odd that ToList() should return null ever.  Also, are you sure you have matching items with the 'parentId' being used?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1194982/183367

Comment: Julien Lebosquain, thanks very much! It's what i find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When you write:

```
.Where(m => m.ParentId == parentId)
```

it converts to T-SQL as:

```
WHERE ParentId=null -- incorrect T-SQ evaluation against NULL
```

2) When you write:

```
.Where(m => m.ParentId == null)
```

it converts to T-SQL as:

```
WHERE ParentId IS NULL -- correct T-SQL evaluation against NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string parentId == null;
```

should be:

```
string parentId = null;
```

Comment: Year, i now :) Sorry, i have mistake in the post.

Comment: Only in the post? Is the problem still occuring?